# Better strategy for bot posting messages to multiple channels with DiscordJs

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I am trying to execute bot functions from a node express server and it *seems* the best option is the DiscordJs package (correct me if I'm wrong for this use-case). For example, a user takes some action on my web application that would grant them a role to access different channels. The DiscordJs docs all seem to focus on actions like this being prompted from the discord server through bot commands or detecting changes with members.

I would like to execute bot functions from my express server by instantiating one client, logging that client in, and executing functions from the server. Something to the effect of

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"]});
client.on("<some event on express server>", (event) =>{
   //event actions
});
client.login(token)
```

Is DiscordJs the right tool for this use case? Should I be using something other than Discord.Client to do this? Any suggestions/input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DiscordJs is a great package, I have a fair amount of experience using it.

For your use case I think it would work great.

`client.on(event, function)` will only take *Discord* events as event arguments. These are listed here:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client

You could however use events from your web server using something similar to below

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"]});

yourWebServer.on("yourEvent", (event) => {
  client.doSomething()
}

client.login(token)
```

The main problem to tackle if you wish to use the discord client in this way is identifying the Guild/Message/Role/Whatever you want to change.

Normally, discord bots react to messages so they have access to a lot of data very quickly. In the below example, the bot can get a great deal of information from the message data alone, like the author, the guild it was posted in, the roles in that guild etc. You can see a list of properties here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"]});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
   client.doSomething()
});

client.login(token)
```

If you plan to use this discord bot on just 1 server messing around with your friends or whatever (i do this a lot), you can find your server's Guild ID and hardcode it somewhere into your bot. You can then fetch all roles/messages/users/whatever as you wish.

For any wider usage you'd have to get the context from somewhere else, e.g. inputting ids on a form on your web server.

Have a good read of the discord.js documentation, its very well made in my opinion. Get an idea of what information you want to access, and how you can access it. It will then be easier to determine what context you need to give the bot to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to use discordjs client commands outside of an event listener it is possible but requires diligent use of async/await. Check this thread for more insight https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3100